# Minizinc array of sets combining

Tags: arrays, set, minizinc

Given an array of sets not of the same size, generate an array of sets which are combined pairs of the given sets. Tried various comprehension arrangements. The error message sometimes is "not an integer expression"

```
    int: n = 4;                          % number of groups
    set of int: Grp = 1..n; 
    array[Grp] of int: m = [3,2,2,3]; % sizes of groups
    int: t = sum(i in Grp)(m[i]); % Total number of members
    set of int: PRSN = 1..t;     % a unique id for each member
    % An array of sets of groups.
    array[1..n] of set of int: GrpSets = [{1,2,3}, {4,5}, {6,7},        {8,9,10}];
    % COMBINED GROUPS
    int: r = 2; % number of combines
    set of int: Cmb = 1..r;
    array[Cmb] of Grp: cg1 = [1,2];
    array[Cmb] of Grp: cg2 = [3,4];  % gc1[1] to be combined with gc2[1] ...
    % generate array of combined sets. Both versions fails.
    %array[PRSN] of set of int: CmbSets = [ {GrpSets[cg1[k]] union         GrpSets[cg2[k]]}| k in 1..r];
    array[PRSN] of set of int: CmbSets = [{GrpSets[cg1[1]] union         GrpSets[cg2[1]]}, {GrpSets[cg1[2]] union GrpSets[cg2[2]]}];
    % Expected outcome CmbSets = [{1,2,3,6,7}, {4,5,8,9,10}]
    solve satisfy;
    output ["CmbSets = ", show(CmbSets),
              ";\n" ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of problems with your two definitions of `CmbSets`:

```
array[PRSN] of set of int: CmbSets = [ {GrpSets[cg1[k]] union         GrpSets[cg2[k]]}| k in 1..r];
array[PRSN] of set of int: CmbSets = [{GrpSets[cg1[1]] union         GrpSets[cg2[1]]}, {GrpSets[cg1[2]] union GrpSets[cg2[2]]}];
```

1) The set `PRSN` should be `1..2` (not `1..10`) since there are only two elements in the array `CmbSets`. Perhaps you meant `1..r`?

2) When using `union` you should not embrace the expressions with `{...}`. This is why you get the - somewhat unclear - error message `"not an integer expression"`

Here are two working variants:

```
array[1..r] of set of int: CmbSets = [ GrpSets[cg1[k]] union GrpSets[cg2[k]]| k in 1..r];
```

and

```
array[1..r] of set of int: CmbSets = [GrpSets[cg1[1]] union GrpSets[cg2[1]], GrpSets[cg1[2]] union GrpSets[cg2[2]]];
```

Comment: Thanks hakan. I'm quite sure I did try it without the {} - I realise the union of sets is a set -  but maybe I was making an error elsewhere. Your version works a treat. I had spent time experimenting with ++ concat rather than union but that's a dead end as it yields an array and you can't have an array of arrays. Regards George

Comment: Excellent. If you're happy with the answer, please accept it.

Comment: Apologies. How does one accept a solution other than via a comment?

Comment: Under the two arrows to the left of the answer, there is a check mark. Click on it to accept the answer. More about this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers